# Border Radius Create

Tags: javascript, html, css

Anyone who make is toggle menu. I am trying a long time i am unable to make this toggle menu below are the my html file and css and attach pic create same this. i want to create border radius like this picture for mobile screen.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uU2Zy.jpg)

Below are my code pasted anyone can do this. I am very thankful to you

```css
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.hero{
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 100vh;
    background: #eceaff;
    color: #525252;
}
nav{
   
   
    padding: 20px 10%;
    
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    position: relative;
}


.user-pic{
    padding: 15px;
    float: right;
    border-radius: 50rem;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 50rem;
        
    
  
}



nav ul{
    width: 100%;
    text-align: right;
}
nav ul li{
    display: inline-block;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 10px 20px;
}
nav ul li a{
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
}

nav ul li a:hover{
    color: yellow;
}
.sub-menu-link{
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 50rem;
}
.sub-menu-wrap{
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    right: 10%;
    width: 320px;
    max-height: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
    
}
.sub-menu-wrap.open-menu{
    max-height: 400px;
    margin-top: 30px;
}
.sub{
    background: rgb(245, 7, 7);
    padding: 20px;
    width: 65%;
    margin: 10px 0.5px 0px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 2rem;
    opacity: 1;
}
.sub-menu{
    background: rgb(245, 7, 7);
    padding: 20px;
    margin: 0px 0.5px 40px 0.5px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 1rem;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 1rem;
    border-top-left-radius: 1rem;
}
.user-info{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
.user-info h3{
    font-weight: bold;
}
.user-info span{
    width: 60px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin-right: 15px;
}

.sub-menu-link{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #525252;
    margin: 12px 0;
}
.sub-menu-link p{
    width: 100%;
}
.sub-menu-link img{
    width: 40px;
    background: #e5e5e5;
    border-radius: 50%;
    padding: 8px;
    margin-right: 15px;
}
.sub-menu-link span{
    font-size: 22px;
    transition: transform 0.5s;
}
.sub-menu-link:hover span{
    transform: translate(5px);
}
.sub-menu-link:hover p{
    font-weight: 600;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <!-- Creadted by Coding Pakistan Youtube Channel -->
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title> Menu</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>


    <div class="hero">
        <nav >
            <div class="p">
           <div  onclick="toggleMenu()" class="user-pic">
            <span >CK</span>
        </div></div>
       
            <div class="sub-menu-wrap" id="subMenu">
                <div class="sub">
                   
                </div>
                <div class="sub-menu">
                    

                    <a href="#" class="sub-menu-link">
                        <img src="images/profile.png">
                        <p>User Profile</p>
                       
                    </a>

                    <a href="#" class="sub-menu-link">
                        <img src="images/help.png">
                        <p>Privacy and Safety</p>
                        
                    </a>

                    <a href="#" class="sub-menu-link">
                        <img src="images/setting.png">
                        <p>Settings</p>
                        
                    </a>

                    <a href="#" class="sub-menu-link">
                        <img src="images/logout.png">
                        <p>Sign Out</p>
                        
                    </a>

                </div>
            </div>

        </nav>
    </div>

<script>
    let subMenu = document.getElementById("subMenu");
    
    function toggleMenu(){
        subMenu.classList.toggle("open-menu");
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this:

```css
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.hero{
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 100vh;
    background: #eceaff;
    color: #525252;
}
nav{              
    padding: 20px 10%;        
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    position: relative;
}
.user-pic{
    padding: 15px;
    float: right;
    border-radius: 50rem;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 50rem;
    border: 15px solid rgb(245, 7, 7);
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 15px rgb(245 7 7);
}

nav ul{
    width: 100%;
    text-align: right;
}
nav ul li{
    display: inline-block;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 10px 20px;
}
nav ul li a{
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
}

nav ul li a:hover{
    color: yellow;
}
.sub-menu-link{
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 50rem;
}
.sub-menu-wrap{
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    right: 9%;
    width: 320px;
    max-height: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;        
}
.sub-menu-wrap.open-menu{
    max-height: 400px;
    margin-top: 44px;
}
.sub{
    background: rgb(245, 7, 7);
    padding: 20px;
    width: 65%;
    margin: 10px 0.5px 0px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 2rem;
    opacity: 1;
}
.sub-menu{
    background: rgb(245, 7, 7);
    padding: 20px;
    margin: 0px 0.5px 40px 0.5px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 1rem;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 1rem;
    border-top-left-radius: 1rem;
}
.user-info{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
.user-info h3{
    font-weight: bold;
}
.user-info span{
    width: 60px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin-right: 15px;
}

.sub-menu-link{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #525252;
    margin: 12px 0;
}
.sub-menu-link p{
    width: 100%;
}
.sub-menu-link img{
    width: 40px;
    background: #e5e5e5;
    border-radius: 50%;
    padding: 8px;
    margin-right: 15px;
}
.sub-menu-link span{
    font-size: 22px;
    transition: transform 0.5s;
}
.sub-menu-link:hover span{
    transform: translate(5px);
}
.sub-menu-link:hover p{
    font-weight: 600;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <!-- Creadted by Coding Pakistan Youtube Channel -->
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title> Menu</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="hero">
        <nav >
            <div class="p">
           <div  onclick="toggleMenu()" class="user-pic">
            <span >CK</span>
        </div></div>
       
            <div class="sub-menu-wrap" id="subMenu">
                <div class="sub-menu">                       
                    <a href="#" class="sub-menu-link">
                        <img src="images/profile.png">
                        <p>User Profile</p>                           
                    </a>
                    <a href="#" class="sub-menu-link">
                        <img src="images/help.png">
                        <p>Privacy and Safety</p>                            
                    </a>
                    <a href="#" class="sub-menu-link">
                        <img src="images/setting.png">
                        <p>Settings</p>                            
                    </a>
                    <a href="#" class="sub-menu-link">
                        <img src="images/logout.png">
                        <p>Sign Out</p>                            
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </div>

<script>
    let subMenu = document.getElementById("subMenu");
    
    function toggleMenu(){
        subMenu.classList.toggle("open-menu");
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```